# OverlappingFileLockException after upgrade to the Gradle 3.0.1 version

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I have this exception after upgrade to the Android Gradle 3.0.1 version.
I use Jacoco in my multimodule android project.

```
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:1063)
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.lock(FileChannel.java:1053)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_290345e.output.FileOutput.openFile(FileOutput.java:69)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_290345e.output.FileOutput.writeExecutionData(FileOutput.java:53)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_290345e.Agent.shutdown(Agent.java:137)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_290345e.Agent$1.run(Agent.java:54)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue during Jacoco report generation. my issue was solved by adding the following entries on the build.Gradle file

```
jacoco {
     toolVersion = "0.8.8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Github issue](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/478) (not yet fixed), you should add this to your tests :

```
@PowerMockIgnore("org.jacoco.agent.rt.*")
```